# What is the loops time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to identify the time complexity of the loops below.

Are these the right thoughts about time complexity?

#### Loop 1

```java
for (auto i = 1; n > 0; n -= i, i +=2) {}
```

My thoughts: O(n)

Because `i` has only linear changes and if `n` --> +infinity, then `n-i` doesn't matter.

#### Loop 2

```java
for (auto i = 1; n > 0; n -= i, i += i / 2) {}
```

My thoughts: O(n)

Because we have a geometric progression of `i`:

```
i_n = i_1 *(3/2)^(n - 1)
```

Comment: Subtraction from n is just perplexing. O(n) and O(logn), respectively.

Comment: Having three semicolons in a `for` statement is confusing.

Comment: The second is O(n) because `i` is always 1 (assuming this is C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first is O(√)**

Let's first rewrite it to not change , as that is confusing. Let's introduce  to take that changing role:

```java
for (auto i = 1, m = n; m > 0; m -= i, i +=2) {}
```

follows the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7, ...

After  iterations:

= −∑<sub><sub>=1</sub></sub>(2−1)

which is (by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number#Properties)):

−²

The loop ends when −²≤0, i.e. when √≤. As  is a measure of the time complexity, we have O(√)

**The second is O(log)**

The value of  will indeed follow a geometric sequence. Let's again introduce  as the changing value (instead of ), then when  iterations have been made:

=−∑<sub><sub>=1</sub></sub>(3/2),

which is (by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)):

=−((3/2)<sup>+1</sup>−1)/((3/2)−1)

=−2((3/2)<sup>+1</sup>−1)

The loop ends when −2((3/2)<sup>+1</sup>−1)≤0, or

/2+1≤(3/2)<sup>+1</sup>, or

log<sub><sub>1.5</sub></sub>(/2+1)≤k+1

Since  is a measure of the time complexity, we have O(log).

Comment: I don't know what the intention of the question is, but the code looks like C++, and so `i` is an int, and `i += i/2` leaves `i` unchanged from 1, making Loop 2 O(n).

Comment: Given the author used factors like `(3/2)` in their analysis, I interpreted the code as pseudo code where the division is a rational division. It would be trivial of course if `i` wouldn't change.